# Views getting wrong output?

Tags: views, 8

I am in little situation while creating D8 views. My scenario:

I have two Content Types:

1. **Page**, with fields:

   - title
   - teaser
2. **Article**, with fields:

   - name
   - reference_page (article have unlimited reference field for)

I want output in each ROW like:

`title` (from *Page*), `teaser` (from *Page*) and `name` of each *Article* where *Page* appears.

I am getting duplicate **Page** fields for each existence of page in **Article**.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to provide more details as we cannot guess what your view looks like, but it can probably be solved by enabling views aggregation in the most right column.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this may be solved by using aggregation

[image]

Change the No to Yes.